# htaccess - redirect user from index.php to another file if url is more than root

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a need where I have 2 files located within the same directory

index.php and room.php

What I want to be able to do it if a user goes to www.example.com it will direct them to `index.php`

If a user types in the url www.example.com/whateverelse/ it will redirect them to `room.php`

Also I would like to capture the extra part of the URL into a variable for instance `whateverelse`

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is very much possible. Use this code in your root .htaccess:

```
# load index.php by default
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [NE,R=301,L]

# for all other requests load room.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$ room.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: does not seem to be working, it messes up all my css and image paths.

Comment: how do I capture the extra part of the url as a variable? For isntance `RewriteRule ^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$ room.php$1 [L,NC]`

Comment: This pattern `^((?!(index|room)\.php).+)$` is already capturing URI in `$1` back reference. That you can use as a query parameter e.g. `room.php?u=$1`

Comment: Hey thanks so much for the solution BTW, I have another question since you seem to know what you are talking about :). Is there a way with this solution to ensure that a trailing `/` (slash) is never present in the url at the end of it?

Comment: Yes sure trailing slash can be removed for all non directories in request, see my updated rule.